# Disable script execution within iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a iframe which contains html.
But when the html contains scripts, the iframe executes it.
Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: check this link http://www.iframehtml.com/iframe-scripts.html  every thing in details

Comment: link ^^^ not working

Answer (score 6):

just enable sandbox is simple way to start with.

```
<iframe src="http://www.cnn.com" width="600" height="600" sandbox=""></iframe>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp